# Is the beneficiary of life insurance responsible for the debt?

Tags: united-states, life-insurance, new-york

My mother and father were going through a divorce, but it wasn't final at the time of her death. She had made me her sole beneficiary. Am I responsible for any of the debt my parents had?

Comment: If you provide more details about when the policy was obtained, who paid the premium, when you were named as the beneficiary, and any other major life events your mother may have had after naming you as the beneficiary, I can give you a better idea of what kinds of legal challenges might be possible.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No you are not.

Sorry about the goings on in your life that is certainly a lot of drama in addition to the loss of your mother.

An advantage of having assets pass without going through probate is they do not have to stand for debts of the estate (usually).  The life insurance is yours free and clear.

You do not need to pay for any final expenses, but I would suggest you do.  Make sure your mom has a nice funeral.

Presumably your mother was going to receive part of the marital debts if the divorce had gone through.  Is your father now stuck with all debt or does your mother's estate get her share?  I don't know.  You may want to talk to your mom's lawyer about that.

Let us assume that your father now has all the marital debt.  Should you pay some of it?  That is a judgement call depending upon your relationship with your father, his relationship with money, and the reasons for the divorce.  But that is a judgement call and may alienate you from your father for some period of time.

If her estate gets her part of the marital debt, then there is no need to pay them.

Comment: "Let us assume that your father now has all the marital debt. Should you pay some of it?" - Beware of Tax implications. Technically that could be seen as a donation which often are taxed.

Comment: Right answer, somewhat off on the reasoning, in my opinion. Assuming the OP is in the U.S., then the law of her state probably provides that life insurance usually does not become part of the calculation of the assets and debts of the deceased's estate, but instead goes directly to the beneficiary. (I say "probably" because since this is a legal question the OP would need to talk to a lawyer in her jurisdiction about it to get a decisive answer, and because since we don't know the particular state the asker is in we can only talk about the most commonly applicable rule.)

Comment: But the overall conclusion is very likely right (in my view).

Comment: "You do not need to pay for any final expenses, but I would suggest you do. Make sure your mom has a nice funeral." This is needless proselytizing. Some people don't believe in the value of funerals. Some prefer donations in their name. Some want a party.

Comment: @TomTom is right.  In the US it is called the [gift tax](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p559/ar02.html#en_US_2016_publink1000294289).  You may want to consult with a tax or estate professional.

Comment: Thank you very much for the insights! I have been in contact with a local laywer, and they echoed what you said.

Comment: What about the marital debts?  Does your father now get them all?  Just curious.

Comment: @PeteB.  At this point, it looks like he gets them all.  She was in the process of changing her beneficiaries again, but the paper work got kicked back the day before she died (she forgot to fill out her SSN), so presumably it is still in my name.  Once all that gets sorted out, I will be able to figure out if can help with some of the expenses.

Answer (score 10):

You cannot inherit debts, and the only cases where life insurance can be used to pay the debts of the estate of the deceased are when a living beneficiary was not named on the policy.

It's possible for the life insurance beneficiary designation to be challenged in court, but that is much harder than challenging a will. Unless your father manages a successful legal challenge to you being named as the beneficiary, that money is yours and does not include any obligation to pay debts incurred by your mother.

Comment: I suspect there are variations by jurisdiction.  I'm pretty sure that I, as a married person in a community property state, am not allowed to designate someone other than my spouse as a primary beneficiary (at least for certain plans) without getting my spouse's written consent.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy we know that the jurisdiction is New York. The additional information I asked for would allow a more thorough discussion.

Answer (score 7):

There is one example I can think of in which you would be responsible for the debt of a life insurance policy owner -- if your mother had universal life insurance or whole life insurance, she would have had the right to borrow from the issuer against the cash balance of the policy. The balance of the loan would be deducted from the death benefit when the policy pays out, effectively forcing the beneficiary to pay her debt.

This debt could never be larger than the cash value of the policy and, of course, if your mother had only other kinds of debt, this would not apply at all.

Comment: You might in certain conditions lose the value of the life insurance, but after that the debt is not yours.  So if you have 100,000 in debt 10,000 in life insurance you don't have to pay the 90k back.  You just don't get the 10k